# Sleeping Barber FIFO (without starvation) on semaphores

Tags: c, linux, synchronization, semaphore, fifo

I am trying to implement the solution of a sleeping barber problem. I wrote the following code for barber:

```
while(1){
sem_wait(semsid, mutex);
if(semctl(semsid, customer, GETVAL, 0) == 0){
  logg("...zzz...zzz...\n");
}

sem_signal(semsid, mutex);

sem_wait(semsid, customer);

sem_wait(semsid, isSomeoneCut_sem);
FIFO->isSomeoneCut = 1;
sem_signal(semsid, isSomeoneCut_sem);

sem_wait(semsid, mutex);      //blokujemy dostęp do kolejki
int* tmp = qpop(FIFO, addrFifo);
int pid = tmp[0];
int sem = tmp[1];
FIFO->customers--;
sem_signal(semsid, sem);
sem_signal(semsid, mutex);    //.odbblokowujemy kolejkę


cutHair(pid);
sem_wait(semsid, customerDone);   //razem kończymy strzyżenie
sem_signal(semsid, barberDone);

sem_wait(semsid, isSomeoneCut_sem);
FIFO->isSomeoneCut = 0;
sem_signal(semsid, isSomeoneCut_sem);
}
```

And the following for customer:

```
sem_wait(semsid, mutex);
sem_wait(semsid, isSomeoneCut_sem);

if(qisFull(q)){    //queue is full, leaving
  logg("queue is FULL, leaving.\n");
  sem_signal(semsid, isSomeoneCut_sem);
  sem_signal(semsid, mutex);
  sleep(1);
  continue;
}
else if(qisEmpty(q) && q->isSomeoneCut == 0){
  logg("Nobody's waiting, waking the barber.\n");
}
else{
  q->customers++;
  logg("Taking a seat in waiting room.\n");
}

sem_signal(semsid, isSomeoneCut_sem);

int mysem = getSemInd(q);
semctl(semsid, mysem, SETVAL, 0);


qpush(q, addrFifo, getpid(), mysem);
sem_signal(semsid, mutex);
sem_signal(semsid, customer);

sem_wait(semsid, mysem);

getHaircut();

sem_signal(semsid, customerDone); //wspólnie kończymy strzyżenie
sem_wait(semsid, barberDone);

logg("I was cut and am leaving the shop.\n");
```

FIFO is kept in a shared memory segment along with flags, amount of customers in a queue etc. When I run the program, I come across one minor problem:
 - Barber cannot instantly set flag isSomeoneCut after waking up (someone can interrupt him and for example wake him up again.
If you see any other problems, please tell me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Indentation/formatting......

Comment: I'm sorry, but we do not perform code review here.  There is another Stack Exchange site for that, but there they expect you to present (believed to be) working code, whereas you seem to stipulate that yours has at least one known flaw.  If you have a specific question about the observed behavior of your code, or if you want help fixing a specific flaw, then do edit your question to say so; those are among the things we do here.